# Modifying existing components within stream

Tags: rtc

I have a component with multiple top level folders which correspond to jar files. Is it bad practice to add new top level folders to this component ( which correspond to new jar files) ? Or should I be adding new components once a component has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad practice isn't so much in adding new top folder, but rather in adding any jar in the first place.

More generally, adding a new component is justified when you have a coherent set of files which can evolves on its own, will be branches or labelled as a all.
It is for *sources* or text data. Not for binaries, especially generated binaries that you can rebuild from the sources.